# Updating UI (via loop) without delay?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I want to change the background of my app while it's running (an infinite loop) - however, the app either stops responding or just blanks completely. I think this is due to using `Thread.sleep(1);` - this will just make the app sleep.

My current code:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void run(){
            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR, green);
            gd.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
            gd.setGradientCenter(0.5f, 1.25f);
            gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
            for(int x = 0; x < 400; x++){
                Thread.sleep(20);
                gd.setGradientRadius((float) 400 - x);
                findViewById(R.id.ms_layout).setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
            }
        }
    });
```

In the for loop, I want the gradient's radius to change and then update the background, however, this doesn't work: I'm guessing when it sleeps the whole application halts and then resumes to find out it needs to halt again.

How can I fix this?
In other words, how can I use a loop to update the UI without disrupting the app's main thread?

Comment: "I'm guessing when it sleeps the whole application halts and then resumes to find out it needs to halt again." -- no, it is because you are not returning control of the main application thread to the framework, so it cannot draw your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call Thread.sleep() on your UI thread. As you say, it freezes the UI. You should do the long work (like Thread.sleep()) in another thread, and then update the UI on the UI thread.

An example from an application I made:

```
private void startProgressThread() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!isPaused) {

                // Thread.sleep() is called off the UI thread
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // The progress bar is then updated on the UI thread
                progressBar.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int time = service.getTimeElapsed();
                        progressBar.setProgress(time);
                        elapsedTime.setText(millisToMinutes(time));                            
                    }

                });

            }
        }

    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't use sleep on the main thread! You need to use a timer, but there's a catch, you can only modify the UI from the main thread, so you need to use a Runnable, as described here: http://www.techsono.com/consult/update-android-gui-timer/

Answer (score 0):

you need to `post` the `Runnable` to be executed again and again in the main thread and not sleep it. something similar to this:

```
GradientDrawable gd;
Handler uiHandler;
private View view;
private void start(){
            // create the drawable
            gd = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR, green);
            gd.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
            gd.setGradientCenter(0.5f, 1.25f);
            gd.setCornerRadius(0f);

            // put it on the view
            view = findViewById(R.id.ms_layout);
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);

            // get a handler for the main thread looper and run
            uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            uiHandler.post(myRun);
}


private Runnable myRun = new Runnable(){

        int x = 0;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void run(){
            for(int x = 0; x < 400; x++){
                // do the change
                gd.setGradientRadius((float) 400 - x);
                // ask system to re-draw it
                gd.invalidateSelf();
                // update n re-post loop
                x++;
                if(x < 400)
                  uiHandler.post(myRun);
            }
        }
    };
```

ps.1: that's all done without testing, you'll have to adjust details yourself.

ps.2: you can also use `postDelayed` like this `uiHandler.postDelayed(myRun, 20);`

**edit:**

in case you want to do something more modular, you could create your own Drawable that extends from `GradientDrawable` and use the `setLevel(int)` to start animation. I do it all the time, something like this:

```
public class MyCustomDrawable extends GradientDrawable{

 // put the same constructors GradientDrawable uses.


    private int x;
    protected boolean onLevelChange (int level){
       x = 0;
       invalidateSelf(); // this will make the thing call draw
    }

    public void draw (Canvas canvas){

        // adjust what to draw
        setGradientRadius((float) 400 - x);

        // let the GradientDrawable do its normal drawing thing
        super.draw(canvas);

        // and then check if it needs another update
        x++;
        if(x < getLevel())
            invalidateSelf();
    }
}
```

put this in the background of your view and call `gd.setLevel(400);` everytime you want to do the animation.

the beauty of this method is that you can adjust it freely for example, based on time if you prefer, level 4 will be 4 seconds so then you make during `onLevelChange` you do the math `long animationEndTime = System.currentTimeMilis() + (level * 1000)` and during the `draw` you call invalidateSelf() `if(System.currentTimeMilis() < animationEndTime)`